# Send associative array through ajax

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax

I was trying to send an associative array of warnings when a button is clicked. It will pass id and type of warning and trigger collect function which stores them into the array as key value pairs. Then I want to send it to another page. The problem is if it is simple array it will work when I call $_POST ['warn']; but if I change it to an associative array I will get error msg saying that warn is not defined. This is my JS code:

```
var warnings = [];
function collect(id,type){ warnings [id]  = type;}
$('#but1').click (function (){
  $.post ("url", {warn: warnings}function(r){alert (r);});
});
```

Is there a way to send the associative array as key value pairs using AJAX to my php page and get the array using `$_POST`?

Comment: You could use JSON.stringify(warnings) and then parse the JSON on your php page

Comment: You're using jQuery, so you're already doing it, the data will be parsed as www-urlencoded, you just have to access the correct keys in PHP

Comment: You're missing a comma between your data and your callback function in the `$.post` call, but that would have caused other issues, so I'm guessing that's a typo.

Comment: JavaScript does not have associative arrays. You should better not use an array, but a plain object. Initialise as `warnings = {};`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your warnings could be constructed like so in JavaScript:

```
var warnings = {

    warning1: {
        id: 1,
        type: 'info'
    },

    warning2: {
        id: 2,
        type: 'danger'
    }

}
```

Then send the `warnings` object as JSON to the server in PHP. You may parse it like so:

```
$json = json_decode(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'warnings'));
```

Be sure that `warnings` corresponds to the data in your ajax call.